# Set data in a channel which is actually set by a mocked function for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, goroutine, hystrix

I am trying to write unit tests for a method(methA) which makes a call through hystrix.Go. The external function i'm calling inside Hystrix func()[somefunc] takes channel as parameter and inserts the data in the channel in actual code flow. While writing units i want to set data into channel and test out all possibilities, Is that even possible?

```
func methA() {
    // some code
    channel := make(chan []string, 1)
    hystrix.Go("x", func() error {
        return A.somefunc(channel)
    }, nil)
    // some code which uses channel
}
```

Comment: From the unit test, you don't have access to the channel. Maybe you can refactor methA() to create a channel and call a methB(channel) so that you can create a channel in the test, and test methB instead.

Answer (score 0):

Test code which uses channel? Maybe you can try to mock `A.somefunc`.

An example is as follows:

```golang
func TestMethA(t testing.T) {
    // All possibilities
    cases := struct {
        data []interface{}  // data that send to channel
        want interface{}
    } {
        // ...
    }

    somefunc := A.somefunc
    defer func () {
        A.somefunc = somefunc
    }()

    for c := range cases {
        A.somefunc = func(c chan) error {
            // set data into the channel.
        }

        // call methodA
        methodA()
    }
}
```